# Background repeat prevent image from showing if it can't be fully displayed

Tags: html, css

When I repeat a background in CSS, I only want to show the image if it can be fully shown.

Do I have to set the width in pixels? Or is there a CSS property that will only show the image if it can be fully shown?

[[image: dotted image not fully shown]]

```
<div align="left" style="padding-left: 30px;">
    <div class="rep_div" style="background:url('file.png'); width:93.5%; display:block;height:3px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what do you expect ?

Comment: He wishes to only have background repeat when the *repeated image* can be fully shown (not cut off)

Comment: I think he tries to achieve something else by using this background hack, to achieve something what probably wouldn't need using background trick at all.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. `background-repeat` usually assumes the entire image would be shown, or else you can't see any repeating anyway. Arnold, what do you want to have happen when the container element is smaller than the image?

Comment: @Roberrrt exactly!

Comment: @SyDy if that is the case I don't want the image to show.

Comment: You don't want to resize the image to fit the element?

Comment: @SyDy no, they have a certain height requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but at face value you will need some JS that measures your div's dimensions, measures your image's dimensions and does a simple comparison, then if the div is the same size or larger than the image sets the div's background-image to the image's url.

Here's a basic approximation using CSS and jQuery

```
/* css */
#container{ ...no image background set here... }

/* js */
var $container = $('#container');
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';
image.onload = function() {
  if (
    $container.outerWidth() >= this.width &&
    $container.outerHeight() >= this.height
  ) $container.css('background-image': 'url('+image.src+')');
});
```

If you are trying to fit exactly the number of repeated images than this code can be easily adapted to not depend solely on "equals or greater", but a multiplication of the image's dimensions.

Be sure to note that this code will only run once, the better practice would be something like this:

```
var $container = $('#container');
var image = new Image();

image.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';

var calculate = function() {
  if (
    $container.outerWidth() >= image.width &&
    $container.outerHeight() >= image.height
  ) {
    $container.css('background-image': 'url('+image.src+')');
  }
  else {
    $container.css('background-image': 'none');
  }
});

image.onload = calculate;
$(window).on('resize', calculate);
```

Comment: is it possible to accomplish this without Javascript? (it's an email template)

Comment: It's not I think, this is the closest possible solution.

Comment: If you are writing an email template, my best advice to you is quit while you're ahead and make it as simple as possible. Most problems like these can be solved on the design planning step where you can simply come up with a different idea/solution that does not have complicated (or in this case impossible) problems.

Comment: @medv that is really good advice, this is already the second time I started over though. Wasted an entire week working on the template, than had the same result in 30 minutes... But in this case, it's _almost_ done so it would be awesome if there is any solution.

Comment: I think the sunk cost fallacy applies here! It's definitely a common experience: spend a lot of time on something and realise you need to re-do it. If I were you, I would still re-start from the design and include as much of your current work as possible without going as far as this image problem. unfortunately email client css support is below acceptable, so some of the solutions that might be possible with CSS3 eg background-size are out of your reach. If you do not want to tamper with the original image scale, then those do not apply either. This is a JS problem, not a CSS one. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, @Arnold I'm not sure that I fully understand your question, but in case it helps, you could use the `background-size` and `background-repeat` properties, for example:

```
<div style="background-image: url('file.png'); background-size: x% y%; background-repeat: repeat-x;">
```

Where x and y are percentages that represent the width and the height, respectively. So if you have an image that is portrait (taller than it is wide), set y to 100% and x to a percentage evenly divisible by 100% that best represents the aspect ratio (so something like 10, 20, 25, 33.3, 50%). This way, your image will repeat evenly along the x-axis, but won't need to on the y because it's taking up 100% of the element height.

(Conversely, if the image is landscape (wider than it is tall), x would be 100% and y would be divisible by 100 and use `repeat-y` instead of `repeat-x`.)

This might take some tinkering and depends on whether the image is something that will look ok with its aspect ratio being off somewhat. It may or may not be the solution you need, but I figured it's worth a shot.